# Command acting different in bash_profile vs terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, osx

`git branch -r | awk '{print $1}'` typed into the terminal yields:

```
origin/HEAD
origin/master
```

while `alias test1="git branch -r | awk '{print $1}'"` in `.bash_profile` yields:

```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

Why is `awk '{print $1}'` ignored in the `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Try to debug this.  Cut out pieces, and replace the ``git`` commands with `cat ` *`filename`* commands, until the behavior changes.  Come back when you have two commands (both of which are fewer than 80 characters long), one of which works correctly and one of which doesn't — and explain what they are supposed to be doing.

Comment: @Scott see update

Comment: Execute `alias test1` after sourcing `.bash_profile` to see what alias you have set, compared to what you may have expected to set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the alias:

```
$ alias test1="git branch -r | awk '{print $1}'"
```

Then look at its definition:

```
$ alias test1
alias test1='git branch -r | awk '\''{print }'\'''
```

See how the `$1` disappeared?  That's because your alias definition was in double quotes.  This meant that the shell expanded the `$1` variable in the string that defined the alias.  Its value was empty.

Use single quotes around your alias definition, escape the `$`, or write a proper function:

```
test1 () {
    git branch -r | awk '{ print $1 }'
}
```

A good rule of thumb may be this: If your alias is more complex than a single command (and require special quoting etc.), then write it as a shell function instead.